How to get and set Analogue Gain of USB Web Camera
Details:
I have been trying to fix the light exposure of my USB Web Camera (ELP-USB8MP02G-L75).
Through opencv I was able to deactivate auto-exposure (cv::CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE) and set the exposure (cv::CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE) to a fixed value. However, I notice that if I open the web-camera using Windows default camera app, auto-exposure will always be set to on automatically and dinamically change the exposure value. My opencv program when executed can just overwrite the value and set auto-exposure to false. However, I still get two completelly different images for the same camera properties parameters, there are still big differences in light exposition after fixing all of these values:
Image 1: Exposure: -7
Image 2: Exposure: -7
All of the parameters in DirectShow are exactly the same (cv::VideoCaptureProperties). But, the images look completely different. I know that auto-exposure changes the Exposure-Time(Shutter speed) and the Gain, however none of these parameters as changed. The issue lies in what Low light compensation on windows default camera app is actually doing/changing.
After researching a little bit more, I realise that the gain from DirectShow and VideoCaptureProperties (cv::CAP_PROP_GAIN) is the digital gain (post processing), and that the camera also has an analogue gain, according to the datasheet of the Camera Sensor (Sony IMX179QQH5-C)
So the two images above, have everything the same, exposure value, auto-exposure off, digital gain, but have a different analogue gain. So my goal is to access this analogue gain, which so far I was not able to access.
What I already tried:
I explored all of opencv Video Capture Properties but I did not find any property related to exposure or analogue gain than the ones I already tried.
I started to explore Windows Media Foundation and access kernel properties, such as KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_EXPOSURE. I found that property MF_CAPTURE_METADATA_ISO_GAINS is most likely and I am looking for but this is a metadata property (I cannot set) but still was not able to get any value out of it.
I know that libcamera library supports this but for my understanding this only works for Linux based OS.
I already contacted the camera manufacturers, but they were unable to help me
Before delving into some of these frameworks, I would like to know if any of this is really possible or not.

Most properties and settings from Media Foundation are exposed by the newer WinRT APIs with generally much simpler access, you should try what you can do with it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.exposurecontrol if this doesn't work it probably means the camera doesn't expose this to Windows (and it's often reflected by what you can do in the official Camera app, eg: if it doesn't work in Camera app nor in WinRT API, the vendor should be able to explain why)

Thank you for the quick reply, @SimonMourier. I used the suggested WinRT APIs but was only able to change the parameters on VideoCaptureProperties, which is the same as DirectShow. I concluded that the camera has, indeed, auto-gain compensation, but I cannot access the analogue gain. It is either the vendor that provides these extra controls or there is nothing I can do since this "gain-compensation" is done by the camera firmware. Thank you anyhow!
